# NSTextField subclass doesn't respect -acceptsFirstResponder?

Tags: cocoa, subclass, nstextfield, first-responder

I'm working with NSTextFields and enabling/disabling selection and editing, and I ran across some strange behavior in a sample app. I have a subclass of NSTextField called MyTextField; the only thing this subclass does is to deny first responder status whenever asked, as in:

```
@interface MyTextField : NSTextField
@end

@implementation MyTextField
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

However, when I place an instance of this text field in a .xib, then launch the app, I can still click into the text field and start editing it. Is the text field ignoring the return value of `-acceptsFirstResponder`?

I've tried a couple things to work around/diagnose this:

- The text field's class is properly set to MyTextField instead of NSTextField in the .xib
- If I place an `NSLog` statement before the `return`, it gets printed to console as expected
- If I return `NO` for `-becomeFirstResponder`, it exhibits the same behavior: I can still edit the field
- If I call `[myTextField setSelectable:NO]` in the view controller, it works as I expect: I'm no longer able to click into the field

  - However, if I return `NO` from `-isSelectable` and `-isEditable` (without calling `-setSelectable:` explicitly), I can still select text in (and edit) the field

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but I think this has to do with the fact that the first responder is not actually the text field, but the field editor, which is a special (non-visible) text view object.  Have a look at the "Working with the field editor" section of the "Text Editing Programming Guide" in the Apple docs to see an explanation.

Comment: I think this is it - denying first responder status doesn't matter for the field editor to appear, but changing the text field's `editable` property does, since that works within the field editor mechanism. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to also set the selectable property, as well.